# Sending Message to Other network in c#

Tags: c#

```
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.contoso.com").AddressList[0];
tcpclnt.Connect(ipAddress, 8001);
```

```html
//Receiver 
TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);
myList.Start();
Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
byte[] b = new byte[100];
string a=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, b.Length);
```

I am trying to send message to other network but it gives error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond _globalIP:8001"
when i try to connect my global ip to the port.

but it works fine if i connect to local ip
please help..
thanks

Comment: Well, probably there are no applications/services listening on 8001 port running at globalIP host.

Comment: i have created listner class also which listens port 8001..

Comment: This could be such a lot of things...maybe your router is stopping traffic in that port, maybe the other router is stopping it...

Comment: there could be a firewall at globalIP that has port 8001 locked down.

Comment: So it works locally but not when you use the public IP? If so, have you opened and allowed connections through port 8001 on the router and firewall?

Comment: Just watch out for "Port Forwarding". I'm sorry but how do you want to develop something if you're not able to use google/brain/whatever